# copy and pasting using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there a way i can use Regex to copy the text that is on  `>one two three four</` and paste it in the place of value: `"1234"` 
there are like 2000 records so i don't want to do it manually

```
 <option value="1234">one two three four</option>
    <option value="1213">blahh blahh</option>
    <option value="1234">Test Test Test</option>
    <option value="2332">copy copy copy</option>
```

Comment: Have you tried any pattern yet? Please share. You know you are looking for a capture group and backreference based pattern replacement? BTW, is it an XML file or just randome tags inside a text document?

Comment: XML file 
and i am not so good in regex

Comment: Write an XSL template and use with XML Tools plugin if you are not that good with regex.

Comment: 1) Don't parse XML with regular expressions. Use a DOM parser instead. 2) This is not a regex writing service. What efforts have you made to do this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually wouldn't recommend this; but, since this seems like a one-time usage on a very specific set of HTML, I'd say it's reasonable. However, my expression is ***very*** specific to the example you showed...if, somewhere in your ~2,000 records, something gets significantly different, you could run into unknown issues.

Find:

```
<option value="[^"]+">(.*?)<\/option>
```

Replace:

```
<option value="\1">\1</option>
```

---

[***Demo.***](https://regex101.com/r/mK7uT7/1)

***Note:*** *There's a chance that Notepad++'s regular expression flavor expects `$1` instead of `\1` (sorry for not being 100% sure).*

Comment: Both `\n` and `$n` are valid. Source: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions